# Debugging a .net core WebApps is incredibly slow

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, ef-core-5.0

I'm absolutely clueless regarding an debugging performance issue, which im facing in a NET 5 solution.

The debugger works very slow in my solution which consists of an Web API (EF Core) and an Blazor server WebAPP. Both projects are targeting NET 5. In general Debugging works as expected, but it is much too slow. I've force all of the logging configuration parameters to "none". But it still takes minutes to launch both projects to get started for debugging. I'm on VS 2019 16.9.2. Does anybody can give me an advice, what could cause the problem.

Sorry for not providing any code, I've absolutely no idea what to share with you as I do not know any origin of my problem.

Comment: i'd try the cmd line if you're using the UI dotnet run projname or vide versa then I can work out if its the dotnet runtime or VS

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue as the poster, and when I run dotnet run, everything is fast and responsive. Is there something else to check in VS?

Comment: Meanwhile I disabled "just my code" debugging and resetted the symbols and their caches. I have not found enough time to do deep Tests. But when I Was debugging a case which was very slow before, I fehlt it got a little bit better. Even this is very confusing, because I would expect that debugging only my code should be faster

Comment: After a few tests it seems that the content of my comment regarding "Just my code" debugging and symbols. Does only have an minor impact on the debugging performance. It heavily depends on the complexity of the components and the pages. Time increases as soon the rendered context is getting more complex. But is slows down much more as I would expect it...I do not have unnecessary complex components in my project. So hav to find another solution for me

Comment: During the week I decided to create exeption rules for iis, devenv and the remote Debugger on Windows Defender Firewall. This made the performance slightly better. Even i am working only on the local host. The most significant thing i noticed is that debugging gets terrible slow when both projects (webapi and blazor) are launched for debugging at the same time. When only one is set up for debugging and the other one is started without debugging I am able to work. But it is still not as fast as i could be. CPU and RAM utilization are always very low

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. My VS is VS Community 2019 version 16.11.2. The web project is net5.0. It takes about 5 seconds to go to the next line.